# Converting a Portrait Profile Image to Square

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I've been given the task recently to convert a portrait image of my boss with the size `489w x 835h` to a good profile image to be used for his LinkedIn profile (`200px x 200px`).

I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to make a picture standout after the image size is modified?

The image that was originally provided did not have a white background but I have requested an image to be provided that was taken further to allow more room in the picture if needed.

Comment: I think this is ***entirely*** dependent upon the photo. Some are simple enough to crop, others need scaling then cropping. Others just require an *interesting* crop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice question. Actually, I have a couple of tips for cropping a portrait (human figure) in a square shape.

1. the eyes' position must be in the top 1/3 of the square.
2. that means you can crop off the top of the head.
3. show the background from a part of the cropped image.
4. try to avoid that the head appears too big.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the ruleset, I agree with them. I'm awaiting to see if we get much else in the way of answers but this is a sure winner.